# Связать метки [сессия] и [session]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

В настоящий момент у нас есть 2 метки [session](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) и [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f). Нужно сделать [session](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) синонимом [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f).

Comment: А вдруг сессия студенческая? :) Тогда это учебное-задание. :)

Comment: @Discord, а ведь я предлагал изменение описания этого тега, и оно прошло. Я не понимаю, почему там нет описания. Именно для этого, я добавлял описание, чтобы студенты не использовали этот тег в качестве студенческой сессии, т.к. прецеденты были.