# От [сессии] до [сессии] живут метки сомнительного качества

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Объединить:

- [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f) — 151 вопрос,
- [сессии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8) — 47 вопросов.

Краткое описание у меток одинаковое. Синонимизация с меткой [session](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) [уже осуществлена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384/199934).

Также я не уверен в необходимости, пользе этих меток. Они проставляются к вопросам о самых разных языках программирования и фреймворках.

Comment: We need moar pun!

Comment: Удалить их! Метка о землянах "[tag:Earth]" мало чем поможет в поиске конкретных тем. Разве что преподавателю чтобы отслеживать нерадивых студентов :)

Comment: @Other, `Они будут учить тебя пытаться доказать, что ты прав, я говорю тебе — докажи, что ты, ошибаешься.`, **Луи Пастер**. Возможно, появятся аргументы  к оставлению меток. Сам придумать таковых я не смог.

Comment: Выражение интересное, но я не согласен. Если **сейчас** аргументов нет - то и меток не нужно делать. **Когда** появится нужда в них - только **тогда** стоит их сделать. Сейчас они только народ путают в назначении и разнообразии.

Comment: @Other, не то хотел сказать. Не исключено, что у других участников имеются релевантные аргументы к оставлению. Если таковые не появятся, тогда попросим удалить метки.

Comment: Я понял что Вы сказать хотели. Но я уверен что таковых не появится, если весомые аргументы у кого-то и были бы, то их написали бы в первые 10 мин. А народ только плюсует, но не отвечает...

Comment: @Other, а я не уверен. На мои вопросы не раз отвечали и спустя несколько дней. По моему вероятностному суждению, — если проблема не критическая, — оптимальный срок, чтобы мета-активные участники увидели вопрос и могли высказаться — неделя. // Тут ещё непонятно, что плюсуют — объединение или удаление, возможно, раз нет не слышно аргументов, стоит голосование запустить.

Comment: Ради Бога, я не против. Но только этот движок не предусмотрел голосовалок. Только методом создания ответов общих, что больше на хак похоже.

Comment: @Other, сделал, голосуйте.

Comment: Первый пошёл! А Ваше какое мнение?

Comment: Выполнил объединение. Основной меткой назначил [единственное число](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/327/6).

Answer (score 8):

Объединить метки [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [сессии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8), но не удалять их.

Answer (score 6):

Удалить метки [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [сессии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8).

Answer (score 0):

Не удалять и не объединять метки [сессия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [сессии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8).